# Synchronization of SharePoint 2010 List with SQL Server Table

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, external-list

I need to create a list such that the values on the list can be stored in SQL table as well.

I need to attach workflows to the list item as well. Its a simple workflow with two approval process involved.

Can we achieve this without using codes at all.

Is BCS a good approach so that any decision made based on Workflow will be stored back to the SQL table?

I have used BCS to read from table but I will need to update as well as delete data that will mostly be handled from SharePoint Side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Business Connectivity Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740.aspx) is what you are looking for! BDC was in SharePoint 2007 which was evolved to BCS in SharePoint 2010

There are few limitations when you work with External Lists, External Content Types and Business Connectivity Services... One of the most important is that **you cannot associate workflows with them!**, a complete list can be found here:
[Business Connectivity Services Limitations](http://pravahaminfo.blogspot.com/2012/01/business-connectivity-services.html)

But when you are working with BCS, that means you have SharePoint Enterprise, and alternate can be to use InfoPath based forms with custom Web Service!

InfoPath form will handle different views for approvers and so on, and on click will call WCF Web Service which will handle notification and data updates to SQL Server directly... As you must know that either you update/add data to SQL Server or External List, both are automatically sync!

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Again, InfoPath forms saves all the data in XML to send the data to SQL table right?

Comment: Yes InfoPath saves data in XML but if you will write your own WCF Web service to listen to InfoPath requests, you will have more control... I have used this structure in one of my project, it works great!

Comment: Rather than adding/updating data directly from InfoPath to SQL Server, write a WCF based Web Service as a middle tier/application tier!

Comment: Is there any good article that I can see to achieve this? If there are any blogs that you may have created.

I have Visual Studio 2005 and .Net Framework 2.0 with VB.NET. Is there basic requirement to create WCF based web service?

Comment: Get Visual Studio 2010 with .Net Framework 4.0! Your life will be easy, WCF was introduced in 3.5 Framework... Also in .Net Framework 4 you can use Entity Framework 4 to work with SQL Server... And VS2010 also has project templates for SP 2010 Development...

Comment: I have to stick with Visual Studio 2005 and .NET framework 2.0. Also the coding has to be done on VB.NET.

Comment: No problem with VB.NET but VS 2005 and .Net 2 is way out-dated when you talk about SP 2010... Why don't you wanna upgrade ?